# Pysimplegui, how to make an active window that updates from json url every 10minute?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

i look around pysimplegui tutorial and copy one of the active window code and append my own request code in getting json file through an url

```
# ----------------  Create Window  ----------------
sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('Black')
layout = [[sg.Text('')],
          [sg.Text('', size=(8, 4), font=('Helvetica', 20), justification='center', key='text')],
          [sg.Text('', size=(8, 4), font=('Helvetica', 20), justification='center', key='test2')],
          [sg.Exit(button_color=('white', 'firebrick4'), pad=((15, 0), 0))]]

window = sg.Window('Running Timer', layout, no_titlebar=True, auto_size_buttons=False, keep_on_top=True,
                   grab_anywhere=True)


# ----------------  main loop  ----------------
while (True):
    # --------- Read and update window --------
    event, values = window.read(timeout=0)


    # --------- Do Button Operations --------
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break

    response = requests.get('https://test.con/tracking.json')

    # --------- Display timer in window --------

    window['text'].update(response.json()[0]['code']+": "+str(response.json()[0]['nav']))
    window['test2'].update(response.json()[1]['code'] + ": " + str(response.json()[1]['nav']))
    count += 1
# Broke out of main loop. Close the window.
window.close()
```

this has a problem of the application keep on getting the json file in the loop. I would like to make it to get the data every 10mins and i also need the first data to get on the first app opening as well.

Comment: Why don’t you try changing `timeout=0` to `timeout=10*60*1000` (I’m guessing the timeout is in milliseconds, adjust appropriately if it isn’t). And to get the data before opening the window, try moving `window.read()` to __after__ having incremented `count`?